# Pulling qlikview data to excel from excel with vba

Tags: excel, vba, qlikview

Is it possible to, from Excel, connect to a qlikview server  and fetch data? I know exporting from qv to excel is a nobrainer but have not found a way from Excel. I am thinking of connecting, then selecting qv data and then fetching result, and all of this with vba from excel. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write load script which will extract the data from QlikView. Or you should use the data load wizard in QlikView. You need QlikView Desktop to do this.

Comment: Can the load script be in excel vba or does it have to be  created inside QlikView? I have no possibility to create any script or manipulate QlikView in any way besides the normal user rights to view data.

Comment: This is a fundamental security rule. Without having access to the QVW file, you will not be able to load or write any script.

Comment: Ok. I am on daily basis exporting the same QV data to excel in order to perform calculations and wanted to automize things a bit, but I guess thats not possible then. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: It is possible to automate but you need access to the QVW file. You can use the QlikView COM API to modify the data into whatever format you need.